# Pushing Function To Array converts Array to a number

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, function

I am trying to implement a custom `EventEmitter`. Here is the class:

```
class EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    this.events = {};
  }

  emit(eventName, args) {
    let functionsToExec = this.events[eventName] || [];
    console.log(functionsToExec);
    console.log(typeof functionsToExec);
    for (let i = 0; i < functionsToExec.length; i++) {
      functionsToExec[i](...args);
    }
  }

  on(eventName, functionToExec) {
    this.events[eventName] = (this.events[eventName] || []).push(functionToExec);
    console.log(functionToExec);
    console.log(typeof functionToExec);
    console.log(this.events);
    console.log(typeof this.events[eventName]);
  }
}

module.exports = new EventEmitter();
```

Where I am using this class, I am doing:

```
eventEmitter.on('test', msg => console.log(msg));
eventEmitter.emit('test', ['hi']);
```

However, on emitting the event, no operation gets performed.
Here are the results of the logs:

`console.log(functionToExec)` - [Function]

`console.log(typeof functionToExec)` - function

`console.log(this.events)` - { test: 1 }

`console.log(this.events[eventName])` - 1

`console.log(typeof this.events[eventName])` - number

`console.log(functionsToExec)` - 1

`console.log(typeof functionsToExec)` - number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line

```
this.events[eventName] = (this.events[eventName] || []).push(functionToExec);
```

is pushing the output of `push` function to `this.events[eventName]` which is nothing but number of items in the array.

make it

```
this.events[eventName] = this.events[eventName] || [];
this.events[eventName].push( functionToExec );
```

Answer (score 2):

On this line

```
this.events[eventName] = (this.events[eventName] || []).push(functionToExec);
```

You are assigning the return value of `push()`. You need to separate that expression to two:

```
this.events[eventName] = (this.events[eventName] || []);
this.events[eventName].push(functionToExec);
```

Or, since you aren't actually assigning a value just replacing an undefined to empty array, so this would be more elegant and one liner, too:

```
(this.events[eventName] || []).push(functionToExec)
```

Comment: That one liner won't work if this.events[eventName] is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at this code

```
on(eventName, functionToExec) {
    this.events[eventName] = (this.events[eventName] || []).push(functionToExec);
```

Here you are assigning return value of `.push()` to `this.events[eventName]`. Return value of `push()` is

> The new length property of the object upon which the method was
>   called.

You need to do following to fix this.

```
on(eventName, functionToExec) {
  this.events[eventName] = (this.events[eventName] || []);
  this.events[eventName].push(functionToExec);
```